# Migrate from Subversion to Team Foundation Server

Tags: svn, tfs, migration, tfs-migration

We are looking for any proven migration path for moving a Subversion repository to a Team Foundation Server. Seems that there has been a discontinued product named CS-Converter([ComponentSoftware homepage](http://www.componentsoftware.com/Products/converter/svn2tfs.htm)) but can't find anybody having used it.

Is CS-Converter a solid product, are there any other resources I haven't found or does anybody have some personal experience which can guide us?

UPDATE: Just to clarify, we need to actually move the existing repository from Subversion to Team Foundation Server (orders from up high), so while SVNBridge is nice, it just does do the job. We need a proven, safe way to migrate the repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/dafc9550-1c17-40ae-ad0a-fc463b336507/) is interesting for you.

There's another software mentioned from [Krysoft](http://www.kyrosoft.com) which has been tested and proved working well.

Answer (score 2):

Some SVN projects cannot be migrated until TFS support symlinks which Windows itself already does just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The CodePlex website team rolled thier own homegrown TFS bridging software **[SvnBridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge)**:

> SvnBridge allows you to use
>   TortoiseSVN and other Subversion
>   clients with Team Foundation Server.
>   It converts the calls made by your
>   Subversion client to the API supported
>   by TFS.
>
> SvnBridge works by running an
>   executable on your local machine that
>   acts as the bridge to TFS. You point
>   SvnBridge at the TFS server, and point
>   TortoiseSVN at the bridge running on
>   your local machine. This allows you to
>   use TortoiseSVN with any TFS server
>   without needing to change the TFS
>   server in any way (no need to convince
>   your system administrator of
>   anything!).

You might want to try it out.

Comment: Client-side SvnBridge was a good idea, but for me it did not always work correctly. Codeplex is now using bridging software at their end, which seems a bit more reliable.

Comment: For all folks interested, this tool does NOT support TFS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the easiest way will be to script it.  Since TFS has a managed object model it shouldn't be too difficult to script a subversion call to get each version of the project and then use the object model to check into TFS.

Probably the hardest part of this would be scriping subversion with the TFS scripting easier.  Sounds like an interesting project. :)